# jquery automatically refresh page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to load content of a file to a division using jquery. After loading contents the page refresh automatically.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $("#btn1").click(function(){
                    $("#div1").load("file.txt");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='form1'>

            <input id="btn1" type="submit">
        </form>
        <div id="div1"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

So the contents in division with id `div1` never show up. I put break points to check whether file loads or not. It load successfully. Because of page refresh  automatically the contents never displays.

Help me to fix it

Comment: I would go with `type='button'`..Simple!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prevent the default action of the submit button.

```
$("#btn1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#div1").load("file.txt");
});
```

Comment: @AbhijithPHaridas . Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

That is because you have a button inside your form

add a `e.preventDefault();` and you should be fine

```
$("#btn1").click(function(e){
      $("#div1").load("file.txt");
      e.preventDefault();
});
```

the other way would be change your html and make your input as

`type="button"` instead of `type="submit"`

The submit button inside a button will trigger a submit when clicked, which is causing your page to reload

Comment: That won't work, you forgot the e inside function parameters `$("#btn1").click(function(e){`

Answer (score 0):

That because you have put the button inside a `form` without an `action` attribute, which then defaults to the page itself. So basically what happens is that it is loading the contents of your file and then posting a form to itself, which causes the refresh.

Why do you need a form anyway? Change the button to `<button id="btn1">Click here to load</button>` and place it outside of the form. Or change the function to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn1").click(function(e){ // e is the event object
        e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the form from posting.
        $("#div1").load("file.txt");
    });
});
```